# The male name "Feivel" transposed for girl

Tags: names, women

My deceased father's Hebrew name was Feivel. I am now pregnant with a girl, but would like to name her after him. Can anyone please share any female equivalent Hebrew names to Feivel?

Answer (score 4):

'Orah' in Hebrew (אורה), the feminine for 'light' or 'her light', is fairly close to 'Feivel' which originates from 'Feivish' (פייבוש ~ Phoebus).

'Me'irah' (מאירה = lights, shines) is also similar though some refrain from giving the name since when not vocalized (properly) the word, in rabbinic Hebrew ('mi'eirah'; short 'i'), means 'curse, poverty'.

In modern Hebrew another name can be 'Zoharah' (ז(ו)הרה = shine, bright).

Alternatively, according to the answers (and links) given to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7686/15571) question, which suggest 'Feivish' comes from the Latin 'life', the most accurate equivalent in the feminine would be 'Chaya'.